# Eclipse IDE, C# and VB.Net plugins that supports .Net Framework4.0

Tags: c#, vb.net, eclipse, plugins, .net-4.0

I want to use C# and VB.Net in Eclipse 3.7 Indigo.

C#

I knew Emonic could supports .Net Framework from 1.0 to 3.0, but the latest version was released on 07 Jan 2010
Improve C# Plugin was quite old.

VB.net

I could not find the plugin about VB.net in Eclipse.

So I want to know is there a plugin for Eclipse that allows you to write C# or VB.net code using the .Net Framework 4.0 or 3.5?

Thanks for all anyway!

Sunny

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Microsoft Visual studio.net is the best commercial IDE for C# and VB.NET.
 
and [sharpdevelop](http://sharpdevelop.net/) is the best open source one with **Form Designer**.